# How to upload file to AWS S3 with presigend url and Aws::FStream?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, aws-sdk

I want to upload a file from my system to an AWS S3 server. I am using the presigned url that allows me to upload a file.

It has to happen with a stream because we want to gzip the file during the upload in the future. I tried using the HttpClientFactory and was able to download a file with a stream.

Sadly I am stuck on the upload. I am not sure how to fill the request with a stream that is able to read a file from my system.

I tried to fill the request with a StreamFactory but was not able to initialize one with my Aws::FStream.

```
auto url = client->GeneratePresignedUrl("bucketName", "s3Key", Aws::Http::HttpMethod::HTTP_POST, 3600);

static std::shared_ptr<Aws::Http::HttpClientFactory> MyClientFactory{};
auto MyHttpClient = Aws::Http::CreateHttpClient(getClientConfig());

const std::shared_ptr<Aws::Http::HttpRequest> req(
    Aws::Http::CreateHttpRequest(url, Aws::Http::HttpMethod::HTTP_POST,
        Aws::Utils::Stream::DefaultResponseStreamFactoryMethod));

std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStreamFactory> streamfac;
Aws::New<Aws::FStream>("C:/Development/test3.txt", std::ios_base::in);

std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStreamFactory>
//Stuck here: req->SetResponseStreamFactory(???)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.

```
auto inStream = std::make_shared<boost::filesystem::fstream>(filepath, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

req->AddContentBody(inStream);

auto res = MyHttpClient->MakeRequest(req);
```